# Line integral segment of parabola

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Suppose
$$
\vec{F} = \nabla f(x,y) = 6y \sin (xy) \vec{i} + 6x \sin (xy) \vec{j},
$$
and C is the segment of the parabola $y = 5 x^2$ from the point $(2,20)$ to $(6,180)$. Then, what is
$$\int_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}\ ?$$

I can not fnd the right answer, tried many ways to do it! could not get so far on this

Comment: Hint
$$
\vec F \cdot d\vec r= (6y\sin(xy), 6x\sin(xy), 0)\cdot(x,y,z)=(6xy\sin(xy), 6xy\sin(xy),0)=6xy\sin(xy)\hat i+6xy\sin(xxy)\hat j
$$

Answer (score -1):

Parameterize the curve $C = C(t)$, say letting $t \in [2,6]$ and then $x(t) = t$ and $y(t) = 5t^2$, so
$$
d\vec{r} = d \pmatrix{t \\ 5t^2} = \pmatrix{1 \\ 10t} dt
$$
So now compute
$$
\int_{t=2}^{t=6} 6\sin(xy) \pmatrix{y \\ x} \cdot \pmatrix{1 \\ 10t} dt,
$$
plugging in the correct $x = x(t), y=y(t)$ as  we defined above.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: well I understand the idea, but there is something I still cant get it, what are wee doing with the y and the x ?

Comment: @user131040 You must express them in terms of $t$, as we defined when we parameterized the curve.

Comment: yeah but what they are equal to with respect to t

Comment: @user131040 i thought the text specified this pretty clearly

Comment: I still can not get the answer!

Comment: @user131040 please be more specific, i am not telling you the answer. But will comment on what you are doing exactly if you tell me the steps you took. What are you using for $x,y$ and which integral are you taking?